# Xamarin KeyStore PasswordProtection field

Tags: java, xamarin, keystore, android-keystore

I'm utilising the JAVA KeyStore class to store my users OAUTH tokens for things like Dropbox.

It's working as it is, but I'm concerned about the security of it as I know very little about how, or where it is stored.

http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/ZPR/c-android-xamarin-monodroid-sqlcipher-correct-way-to-store-encryption-key-for-sqlcipher-database

I am basing my code off of the sample above, one thing that is not provided is why the Password field is null.

So my question is, should this be null?  Or should it contain a password that is unique to my application, if the latter, where would I protect my apps password, as I'm in a bit of a chicken and an egg scenario here.

Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one thing that is not provided is why the Password field is null.

The issue in that implementation becomes what "password" should be used.

> I'm in a bit of a chicken and an egg scenario here.

If a password was hardcoded within the application you might as well use `null` (IMHO... but I've worked with security researchers and have seen their toolkits and a hardcoded password supplied to a method call is less than 2 minutes of work for them to crack, so I would imagine a hacker can have it in even less time ), same as if the "password" was retrieved dynamically from a Web API over a *non-secure* channel.

**Note**: It is not that I am saying using a Null/blank password is OK, I am **NOT**, continue reading.

Prompting the user to input a password (in the form of a swipe pattern, passphrase, pin, etc..) before each keystore usage would make that implementation way "more secure", but at what cost of app|user usability, only you and your users can that determine that for the app's use-case. Personally I like it when my banking app prompts me for a pin and verifies that access via an SMS and another pin to entry, but that might just only be me.

FYI: Being able to nick' your user's OAUTH tokens for multiple sites via just one app and password would be quite enticing for most hackers and researchers.

> It's working as it is, but I'm concerned about the security

And you should be.

That implementation you are referring to, IMHO, is very weak. At a minimum, it should be checking and using Android Keystone provider (`AndroidKeyStore`) if the app is running on at least API level 18. If your app only supports 18+ (or is running on a 18+ device), you should NOT be maintaining your own keystore file (again IMHO... but I can not imagine a security researcher disagreeing, but would love to hear their argument if they think you should).

Using the keystore provider removes you and your app from creating/maintaining/securing that keystore file as the OS does it and it uses the user's token/password/pin/lock-pattern/etc... to secure the actual filestore itself. **No more chicken-egg problem.**

Of course this does not cover your app checking for rooted device execution, malicious app installs, current security exploits tests, non-patched and/or missing security patches, etc... but at least it is a start . (I've worked in some really secure devops environments).

Also that implementation is not checking for secure hardware; ie. KeyInfo.IsInsideSecurityHardware, KeyInfo.IsUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware, etc....

Google has some good keystore training material that covers subjects like the keystore provider:

> https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#java

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely informative and very helpful.  Thankfully I've only just implemented this so not yet released a version of my code with it in.

There is a lot to digest here, and to sum it up, I think what you're suggesting, is either add a pin code lock to the app, or biometrics perhaps.  And use the key from that to secure the keyfile.

Comment: Or, don't manage the keyfile at all and let android do it, using the Android Keystore Provider.  The latter sounds like the perfect solution for me.  So I'm going to look into that method.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Nick Yes, to both of your points. My preferred way is to prompt the user to confirm that they are who they should be (i.e. built-in biometrics (thumbprint/faceid) before opening the Android Keystore Provider based `AndroidKeyStore` that is keyed to your app. (I do not do any apps that support APIs level older than 18 anymore, so I do not manage any keystore files manually, just do not have the need in the apps that I work with...)

Comment: One last question though if I may, if my code is run on a device with the necessary API level, and thus keystore provider.  Will KeyStore.GetInstance(KeyStore.DefaultType); utilise the AndroidKeyStore, and thus my code will not maintain a local file for its keystore, but Android will manage it on its own?

Comment: @Nick You can check what it is via returned string from `KeyStore.DefaultType()`, you should never trust that every vendors/OEM Android 18+ image "might" return `AndroidKeyStore` as the default (Hint: they don't) Perform an API level check (if/else) and directly request `AndroidKeyStore` on 18+

Comment: Note that AndroidKeyStore cannot be used in the way described by the SqlCipher database sample code.  The reason is that the sample code tries to get the secret key out of the keystore.  AndroidKeyStore secret keys are stored in secure hardware which will not return them, ever. Not even the OS has access to them. You can ask AndroidKeyStore to *use* a stored key, to encrypt or decrypt something, but you can't get the key itself out.

Comment: @divegeek Not really true, not at all, you have to verify that the key info is store in a secure enclave (Hint: Not all do) and even then, ensure that the user auth is secured via that enclave, etc...

Comment: @SushiHangover regardless of whether keystore is hardware-backed, AndroidKeyStore provides no API for retrieving secret key material. Also, all devices models launched with Nougat or above are required to have hardware-backed keystore, and nearly all device models launched with Marshmallow did have it, so those that don't are getting rare.

Comment: @divegeek ? You might want to look at that referred implementation again, it retrieving an entry that will be used *as a key* for SqlCipher, it is not retrieving the secret key.

Comment: @divegeek And FYI, I have non-US region devices without secure enclaves in them (one is Oreo-based), another one reports it has secure hardware when it does not and yet another has modified the reply from an SoC via the treble vendor interface...

Comment: @SushiHangover can you provide information about the non-compliant devices? I'll refer them to the appropriate people for enforcement action. Also, how do you know that the devices don't have secure environments?

Comment: @divegeek These "non-approved" devices (and non-Play-based, even though Play was side-loaded on two of them by the reseller at the time of purchase) and two of them are in the hands of a couple of curoius sec-researchers and the other was torn down (image extracted, hardware was mapped, etc...) it still works but is hot-glued to a board in an exploded form as a sec hardware demonstrator. One was a Taiwanese brand impersonator and known about to the brand but the region it comes from precludes any legal enforcement actions against it, it was described to me as a "political matter".

Comment: @SushiHangover ah, yes, non-compliant devices are non-compliant -- and technically not Android.  When it comes to non-Android devices you can't count on any APIs even to work, so you clearly can't expect any guarantees about the nature of the security hardware (or lack thereof).  Indeed, in that case you can't "verify that the key info is stored in a secure enclave", because the KeyInfo methods could easily lie.